# vb.net login control not re-authenticating

Tags: vb.net, authentication, login-control

I am newbie when it comes to working with the vb.net login control so bear with me...

Tp start I am using ASP.net 4.0 and vb.net.

Okay so I have a simple login control that verifies the user against a sql database.  (I am hosting with hostgator so I can't use the normal windows auth).  Now the biggest probelm I am having is that if the session times out and you get redirected to the login page it doesn't matter what you type in the user name/password on the login in form it just lets you right in even if the user name and password are wrong or the user doesn't exist?

How do I make sure that the login control truly authenticates the user?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
Public strLoginErrorMsg As String
Public type As String
Public rowcount As String

Protected Sub login_sbts_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As      System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles login_sbts.Authenticate
    Dim bauthenticated As Boolean = False
    bauthenticated = isValidUser(login_sbts.UserName, login_sbts.Password)

    If bauthenticated Then

        e.Authenticated = True
    Else
        e.Authenticated = False
    End If
    lblInfo.Text = type
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Me.login_sbts.UserName, True)

    If type = "ADMIN" Then
        Response.Redirect("dailynote.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("other.aspx")
    End If

End Sub

Private Function isValidUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal pwd As String) As [Boolean]

    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sbts-scheduling;User ID=userid;Password=password;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from tblusers where UserName='" & username & "' and Password='" & pwd & "'")
    cmd.Connection = con
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    con.Open()
    da.Fill(dt)
    con.Close()
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        strLoginErrorMsg = "Invalid User Name/Password"
        dt.Dispose()
        Return False
    Else
        type = dt.Rows(0).Item("UserType").Trim()
        Session("usertype") = type

    End If
    Return True



End Function

Protected Sub login_sbts_LoginError(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles login_sbts.LoginError
    login_sbts.FailureText = strLoginErrorMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: you should probably post the relevant portions of your web.config file here as well. system.web, authentication, and authorization

Comment: ontop of that, include your front-page code, which should have your asp:login section, or asp:logincontrol .. which ever you're using.

Comment: by the way.. you have SQLInjection Vulnerability here that I did not address in my answer code sample. you should use StoreProcedures and pass those values to your stored procedure using New SqlClient.Data.SqlParameters(@param,"") (in your SqlCommand.Parameter Collection), while assigning SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure. Savy

Answer (score 0):

Actually.. the problem may lye in your call to FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage.. I took the liberty of cleaning up your code a bit though. I also added FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie in your authentication method.. the name and duration of that cookie will be configured in your web.config file.. or your 'configuration settings'.

Unless you're willing to inherit, clear, and replace the ASP.NET default FormAuthenticationModule.. you're going to have to rely on, in part, the web.config configuration settings.

```
Public strLoginErrorMsg As String
Public type As String
Public rowcount As String

Protected Sub login_sbts_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As      System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs) Handles login_sbts.Authenticate
    If isValidUser(login_sbts.UserName, login_sbts.Password) Then
        e.Authenticated = True
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login_sbts.UserName, false, "/")    
        lblInfo.Text = type

        If type = "ADMIN" Then
            Response.Redirect("dailynote.aspx")
        Else
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Me.login_sbts.UserName, True)
            'Response.Redirect("other.aspx")
        End If
    Else
        e.Authenticated = false
    End If
End Sub

Private Function isValidUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal pwd As String) As Boolean
    isValidUser = False
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sbts-scheduling;User ID=userid;Password=password;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from tblusers where UserName='" & username & "' and Password='" & pwd & "'", conn)
    Using conn
        conn.open
        Using reader As system.data.sqlclient.SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
           If reader.Count > 0 Then
                'Not Checking for multible records here.
                While reader.read
                    If Not( IsDBNull(reader("UserType")) Then
                        Session("usertype") = reader("UserType").Trim()
                        IsValidUser = True
                    End If
                End While
            End If
        End Using
        If Not( conn.State = State.Close) Then
            conn.Close
        End If
    End Using
End Function

Protected Sub login_sbts_LoginError(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles login_sbts.LoginError
    login_sbts.FailureText = strLoginErrorMsg
End Sub
```

I recommend you look into inheriting MembershipProvider. It makes working with the asp server tags a bit easier, as you simply specify your provider in the property of the tag. (after you reference and configure it properly in your web.config, app.config.. or through IIS (will require being placed in Global Cache Assembly and all the other loops to becoming a Trusted Provider.)

Comment: conn.state is an enumeration.. and may be 'ConnectionState.Close' or something.. would take a second to lookup.. but.. eh..